# Why does my background stretch to the edges on the top of the page, but not on the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm working to edit the background at the bottom of my webpage and noticed a white border around the background that does not mirror the top portion of the webpage.

I've attempted the usual solution of including `top: 0;` and `right: 0;` I've also included `background-size: cover,` but that has not fixed the issue either.

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgPabv#anon-login) so you can view the HTML and CSS. Note, I'm writing my CSS in SASS, so its a bit long.

I expect the lower background (which transitions from the dark purple to the dark pink) to stretch all the way to the edges, a la the upper background (dark pink to blue), but it instead has a weird white border around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `body` got `8px` margin.

It's easy to notice [with inspection](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (`Ctrl+Shift+C` on Chrome dev tools).

[Reset it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXdYWj):

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and consider accepting the answer